# Associate the right vale to the correct data

Tags: excel, matlab, for-loop, linear-regression, economics

Hi all I need your help.

I downloaded from Refinitiv Eikon several Historical Prices referred to different firms (ex.intesa, unicredit...). Now I have to run a regression in order to estimate the beta and the alfa, but i need to construct the matrix X. This matrix should have the return of a benchmark (ftse mib). The problem can be easily summarize by an example:
Excel sheet

```
unicredit         INTESA             ftsi mib
12/02   2         11/02  www         12/02  a 
10/02   3         10/02  ccc         11/02  b
9/02    4         09/02  xxx         10/02  c
                                     9/02   d
```

In the below section i will show you what should i get:

```
    A                B                  C
unicredit         INTESA             ftsi mib
12/02   2                            12/02  a              
                  11/02  www         11/02  b
10/02   3         10/02  ccc         10/02  c
9/02    4         09/02  xxx         9/02   d
```

I guess i should use a loop (for???), but i don't know how to do...

Matlab or VBA it is fine.

Many thanks in advance,

Luca

Answer (score 0):

[Formulas Used Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFxJC.png)

Spliting of data

```
Cell E2 =IFERROR(VALUE(TRIM(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)))),"")
Cell F2 =IFERROR(TRIM(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(" ",A2,1))),"")
Cell G2 =IFERROR(VALUE(TRIM(LEFT(B2,FIND(" ",B2,1)))),"")
Cell H2 =IFERROR(TRIM(RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND(" ",B2,1))),"")
Cell I2 =IFERROR(VALUE(TRIM(LEFT(C2,FIND(" ",C2,1)))),"")
Cell J2 =IFERROR(TRIM(RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-FIND(" ",C2,1))),"")
```

Lookup Results values

```
Cell L2 =I2
Cell M2 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($L2,$E:$F,1,FALSE),"")
Cell N2 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($L2,$E:$F,2,FALSE),"")
Cell O2 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($L2,$G:$H,1,FALSE),"")
Cell P2 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($L2,$G:$H,2,FALSE),"")
Cell Q2 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($L2,$I:$J,1,FALSE),"")
Cell R2 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($L2,$I:$J,2,FALSE),"")
```